# Numeric edit field in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface

Is an edit field that accept only numeric value (for example, to edit numeric parameters) supported natively (using .NET libraries)?

It's weird that one has to use third party tools for this simple functionality

Answer (score 3):

No, but the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) includes one.

[IntegerUpDown http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpftoolkit&DownloadId=222922](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpftoolkit&DownloadId=222922)

Answer (score 3):

Not directly. You have a few options though:

- use the [Extended WPF toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/), it has some already prepackagaed for you (and it's FREE)
- extend the TextBox control and override the `OnPreviewKeyDown` function to intercept keypresses you are not interested in

Answer (score 0):

another way to achieve your numeric TextBox is to create a AttachedProperty or Behavior. there are a lot of sample code around.

i create a [maskedTextBox](http://blindmeis.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/wpf-masked-textbox-behavior/) behavior for specific input. maybe this can put you in the right direction.